# Intellij/VSCode ballerina debugger don't hit breakpoints

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-vscode-plugin

I have made, super easy, hello world app with main.

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
}
```

I'm making breakpoint like always in IDE "RED DOT"(tried both intellij and vscode)
I go for run debug and it doesn't stop on target breakpoint.
It compiles good, outputs "Hello, World!" as it should

### What I have tried already:

- reinstal ballerina 1.0.4
- reinstal plugins
- tried on both IDEs
- start new project with super easy hallo world

console output under

```
Ballerina Debugging is an experimental feature.
Visit https://ballerina.io/learn/tools-ides/intellij-plugin/using-intellij-plugin-features#debugging-ballerina-programs for known limitations and workarounds.

Waiting for debug process to start...

"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\bin\runnerw64.exe" "C:/Program Files/Ballerina/ballerina-1.0.4/distributions/jballerina-1.0.4\bin\ballerina.bat" run --debug 52376 --sourceroot C:\nieTenKoziol\ballerina-test-debugger mod1
Please start the remote debugging client to continue...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 52376
Compiling source
    nieTenKoziol/mod1:0.1.0

Creating balos
    target\balo\mod1-2019r3-any-0.1.0.balo

Generating executables
    target\bin\mod1.jar

Running executables

Hello, World!
Disconnected successfully from the debug server.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Comment: This is a known bug and will be shipped with the next patch release 1.0.5
https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/19981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in 1.0.4 where debug points are being skipped. This is reported at https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/19981 and a fix is already being sent. Fix will be available with next patch release.

However, remote debugging is working fine with 1.0.4.

Answer (score 3):

So thanks to Aquib Zulfikar, which suggested using version 1.0.2 or 1.0.3 in other ballerina questions, the answer is:
downgrade to ballerina version 1.0.3

After that breakpoints hits normally

I guess there is some bug in 1.0.4 version

edit:

After reinstaling ballerina 1.0.3 there are no variable/locals visible both in vsCode nor in Intellij